# Play song during call

Tags: android

please help me how to play song during call if we are in same
call both should listen that song, and call must be disconnected
automatically once playing done...

present my application behaving like,if i call to anyone once call lifted song is playing but i am only hearing that song but i want to do other person also should listen that song.

but i found in one forum to do like : The closest thing you can do, is have the call set to speaker-phone and then play the voice over the speaker.sounds straight to the mic in a phone call then that would be done.

but that i didn't find in API.

please help me how to do if anyone knows this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in Android -- you do not have access to the in-call audio stream.

The workaround you describe (speakerphone mode) should work, using ordinary media classes (e.g., `MediaPlayer`).

Comment: Even when I try winamp in my phone during a call, it plays sound, but only I can hear it, along with the talks. the person at the other end, doesn't hear it.

Comment: Hi, I also noticed that, During a phone call the media volume gets low. Its the default behavior it seems.